# Firefox Extension, adding Button to Navigation Toolbar (Similar to LiveHeaders and FireBug)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to get a button to appear in the "Customize toolbar" list on Firefox (based on this [tutorial (Custom_toolbar_button)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Toolbars/Custom_toolbar_button)).

[image: Customize toolbar]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/karfnfyi.fze.png))</sub>

In theory, to customize this section of the browser.

[image: Buttons]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/gtyq4tkw.3e5.png))</sub>

Here is my button.xul file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css"
  href="chrome://helloworld/content/button.css" ?>
<!DOCTYPE overlay>
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" id="helloworld-overlay">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://helloworld/content/button.js" />
    <!-- Firefox -->
    <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
        <toolbarbutton id="custom-button-1" />
    </toolbarpalette>
    <!-- button details -->
    <toolbarbutton id="custom-button-1" label="Custom" tooltiptext="My custom toolbar button" oncommand="CustomButton[1]()" class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional custombutton" />
</overlay>
```

And chrome.manifest

```
content helloworld chrome/
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://helloworld/content/button.css

# Firefox
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://helloworld/content/button.xul
```

I've tested my button.xul on Xul Explorer, with good results (it compiles fine).

[image: XUL explorer Custom Button]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/uq21lynt.qww.png))</sub>

For some reason, I am just unable to add this button where I would like for Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to add the necessary `Button` via the [`main.js`](http://www.kendsnyder.com/posts/firefox-extensions-add-button-to-nav-bar) created during [`cfx init`](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk) ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials) with the extension being produced by the command `cfx xps`.

Additionally, I was talking to a developer in `#developer` on the mozilla IRC, and he stated adding the to the Nav Bar programmatically will soon become redundant because the next release of Firefox ([version 29](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/beta/)) will provide functionality to add information the `Navigation Toolbar` using `xul`.

Answer (score 2):

For others who want to do the same but with bootstrap, You have to add to browser pallette.

See this gist here and read the notes:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9467045

Ok edited so now you don't have to think at all. Just copy the code, paste to scratchbad, browser environment of course, and hit run.

It adds a button with an orrange cube as its image, once run the code go to customize and you will see it, you can now drag it to addon bar, toolbar, or australis menu panel.

copy pasted the gist here in case github goes down (lol)

```
var doc = document;
var win = doc.defaultView;

var toolbox = doc.querySelector('#navigator-toolbox');

var button = doc.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'toolbarbutton');
button.setAttribute('id', 'bpMyBtn');
button.setAttribute('label', 'My Button');
button.setAttribute('tooltiptext', 'My buttons tool tip if you want one');
button.setAttribute('class', 'toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional');
button.style.listStyleImage = 'url("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Noitidart/9266173/raw/06464af2965cb5968248b764b4669da1287730f3/my-urlbar-icon-image.png")';
button.addEventListener('command', function() {
    alert('you clicked my button')
}, false);

toolbox.palette.appendChild(button);
```

edit: i updated the code on the gist, so after creating the button it moves it to the `nav-bar` in last position.

Comment: Updated to say its bootstrap method. Try following that method though because I know for a fact that it works.

Comment: Try copy pasting it adds a button vfor me

Comment: Ok ill work on that gist to spoon feed this guy so he can copy paste all without thinking to scratchpad. Right now he has to copy paste portions and give it some thought.

Comment: I've already figured how to do it, with the Mozilla AddOn SDK with the main.js script generated by `cfx init`. But thanks Noitidart (I was going to delete this, but since you've already put effort into it, +1 rep) :). Thanks.

Comment: Welcome i personally like when ppl give me copy paste stuff myself. Its now in my gist library for others to learn from.

Comment: if cfx init was the answer i prefer you remove your acceptance of my answer and answer this question yourself and accept that answer. this is better for searchability.